# add a div markup after subcategory woocommerce

Tags: wordpress

I want to separate subcategories from products "div"

i was try add this code, but it add on all li of subcategories

// define the woocommerce_after_subcategory callback 
function action_woocommerce_after_subcategory( $woocommerce_template_loop_category_link_close, $int ) { 
      echo '

## ' .esc_html__( 'Custom Title Before Products' ) . '

';
};

// add the action 
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_subcategory', 'action_woocommerce_after_subcategory', 10, 2 );

i need after all subcategories add div to separate subcategories

Answer (score 0):

Have find solve

```
add_action( 'init', 'move_subcat_lis' );
function move_subcat_lis() {
    // Remove the subcat <li>s from the old location.
    remove_filter( 'woocommerce_product_loop_start', 'woocommerce_maybe_show_product_subcategories' );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'msc_product_loop_start', 40 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'msc_maybe_show_product_subcategories', 50 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'msc_product_loop_end', 60 );
}
/**
 * Conditonally start the product loop with a <ul> contaner if subcats exist.
 */
function msc_product_loop_start() {
    $subcategories = woocommerce_maybe_show_product_subcategories();
    if ( $subcategories ) {
        echo '<div class="subcategories">'; //custom wrapper
        woocommerce_product_loop_start();
    }
}
/**
 * Print the subcat <li>s in our new location.
 */
function msc_maybe_show_product_subcategories() {
    echo woocommerce_maybe_show_product_subcategories();
}
/**
 * Conditonally end the product loop with a </ul> if subcats exist.
 */
function msc_product_loop_end() {
    $subcategories = woocommerce_maybe_show_product_subcategories();
    if ( $subcategories ) {
        woocommerce_product_loop_end();
        echo '</div>

        <div class="cat_title_new">Товары</div>'; //custom wrapper ends
    }
}
?>
```